# Webhook: run script in one repository after commit on other repo

Tags: git, gitlab, webhooks

In our projects, there are two repos I'm currently interested in: a backend-repo and an app repo.

Now I would like to react on changes in one specific file in the backend repo. Whenever this file is updated, I would like to run a script in the app-repo which ends in creating a merge request.

Is this possible somehow? I went through the integrations-options but couldn't find anything that helped me in this way

Answer (score 0):

You can use bridge-jobs in GitLab-CI if you have that enabled, this way you can let these repo's interact.

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/multi_project_pipelines.html